# TypeError for indexing list with float values in Python

Tags: python, list, tkinter, typeerror, calculator

I'm trying to create a simple calculator with Tkinter. For that, I have created a list that stores the numbers I want to operate with so that I can use the list to add/subtract/multiply/divide. However, when I try to access the list, I receive a TypeError, even though I've converted the values in the list to floats. Here is the error I keep getting: line 37, in calculate

```py
result = operators[current_operator(current_input[0], current_input[1])]
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Here is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox

# take number function
def take_number(event):
    global current_input
    global input_box
    global current_number
    current_number += event.widget["text"]
    input_box.insert(10, current_number)



# take operator event and append current number to number list
def take_operator(event):
    global current_input
    global current_number
    global current_operator
    current_operator = event.widget["text"]
    input_box.insert(10, current_operator)
    current_input.append(float(current_number))
    current_number = ""




# calculate by appending current number to number list and using the list to get first and second number
def calculate():
    global current_input
    global current_operator
    global input_box
    current_input.append(float(current_number))
    input_box.delete(0, 10)
    result = operators[current_operator(current_input[0], current_input[1])]
    input_box.insert(10, result)


# create window
window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Pocket calculator")
current_input = []
current_number = ""
current_operator = ""
# create a dictionary to link to operators
operators = {"+": lambda x, y: x + y,
             "-": lambda x, y: x - y,
             "*": lambda x, y: x * y,
             "/": lambda x, y: x / y}

# create enter box
input_box = tk.Entry(window, text="0", width=10)
input_box.grid(column=0, row=0)

# create buttons
number_0 = tk.Button(window, text="0")
number_0.grid(column=0, row=4)
number_0.bind("<Button-1>", take_number)

for i in range(3):
    one_to_three = tk.Button(window, text=str(i+1))
    one_to_three.grid(column=i, row=3)
    one_to_three.bind("<Button-1>", take_number)

for i in range(3, 6):
    four_to_six = tk.Button(window, text=str(i+1))
    four_to_six.grid(column=i % 3, row=2)
    four_to_six.bind("<Button-1>", take_number)

for i in range(6, 9):
    seven_to_nine = tk.Button(window, text=str(i+1))
    seven_to_nine.grid(column=i % 3, row=1)
    seven_to_nine.bind("<Button-1>", take_number)

c_button = tk.Button(window, text="C")
c_button.grid(column=1, row=4)

dot_button = tk.Button(window, text=".")
dot_button.grid(column=2, row=4)
dot_button.bind("<Button-1>", take_number)

equal_button = tk.Button(window, text="=", command=calculate)
equal_button.grid(column=3, row=3)


sign_button = tk.Button(window, text="+/-")
sign_button.grid(column=3, row=4)

plus_button = tk.Button(window, text="+")
plus_button.grid(column=4, row=1)
plus_button.bind("<Button-1>", take_operator)

minus_button = tk.Button(window, text="-")
minus_button.grid(column=4, row=2)
minus_button.bind("<Button-1>", take_operator)

multiply_button = tk.Button(window, text="*")
multiply_button.grid(column=4, row=3)
multiply_button.bind("<Button-1>", take_operator)

division_button = tk.Button(window, text="/")
division_button.grid(column=4, row=4)
division_button.bind("<Button-1>", take_operator)


# start application
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: List indexes must be integers.

Comment: The indexes are integers, just the values in the list are floats.

Answer (score 0):

Look at `operators[current_operator(current_input[0], current_input[1])]`

`operators` is a `dictionary` with `str` keys and `lambda` values.

You are calling `current_operator(..)` but you need to call `operators[current_operator](..)`

so change your line to:

`operators[current_operator](current_input[0], current_input[1])`